# How can I deactivate Ember-cli JavaScript file concatenation in development?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

By default, Ember-cli automatically concatenates JavaScript files into `vendor.js` and `application.js` (or `<APP_NAME>.js`). This makes tracebacks much less helpful. It appears that the default asset pipeline system, Broccoli, does not have a configuration flag for deactivating concatenation, but it also seems counterproductive to work around this by listing files manually.

Comment: @Mac Cantor, If you do not want the concatenated assets, then you can remove the vendor.js and app.js from index.html and include your JS files separately. But, this will be really a difficult task if your project grows. Can I know the reason why you don't need concatenation? If it is related to debugging, then you have source maps which will help you to get to the correct source file for debugging. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I have not set up source maps correctly. They are being generated at `dist/assets/application.map` and `dist/assets/vendor.map`, but the test runner is showing me errors in `application.js`, and the exceptions are not bubbled to my console, so I can't click on them to jump anyway.

I have to manually open `application.js` and browse to the line described in the traceback.

Did I miss a step? I've re-created a fresh app and pored over the docs for several hours with no change.

Comment: I don't find any problems with the creation of source maps. You can verify it by opening the developer tools -> Source -> check for the <your_application_name>.js file and your complete source code. Having said that, is it possible to share your project's github link if any or let me know the exact version of the Ember-CLI used in your project. Thanks